WebView2 does not display PDF files on some computers
I have a WPF program where use WebView2 control for show some web site and pdf's, the problem come when in some pc's not show correctly the pdf's.
My code in the XAML file is:
<wv2:WebView2
    Width="900"
    Height="1000"
    Source="{Binding FilePDF}" />

And the ModelView file is:
private Uri _filePDF = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
public Uri FilePDF
{
    get => _filePDF;
    set
    {
        _filePDF = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilePDF));
    }
}

private WebView2 _WebViewTC = new WebView2();
public WebView2 WebViewTC
{
    get => _WebViewTC;
    set
    {
        _WebViewTC = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WebViewTC));
     }
}


private void HandleDoc(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
    if (validation != null)
    {
    FilePDF =  new Uri(url);
    }
}

Sorry but I can't show more about the code, but how I say previously this works just in some pc's.
I try to change the logic and the control for WebBrowser but the issues persist. Other things I tried were using Adobe reader and setting it as the default program for these files but that didn't work either, I also made sure that the Webview Runtime was installed and that the URL worked (it's from an AWS bucket so it's a safe source).
Does anyone know what could be happening and how to fix this problem?
